# Adding watermark on image from databases in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, intervention

I am trying to add watermark on image from database in Laravel using Intervention Image package. In my database table I am saving the path of the image. I am using  Accessors in my model to get access to the field of the image path but I am getting this error:

**Method insert does not exist.**

Here is my model:

[image: My model]

Here is my blade:

[image: my view]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not include code as screenshots! Just post it here and style it properly.

Comment: You'd try to insert a watermark in a photo collection, that doesn't work. Try to load the photo from the file path, then insert the watermark photo in there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that mistake of trying to watermark collection of photo. The problem I have is that the website I am working on has been operation for while. Images are being stolen and client need the images to be watermarked. This images already uploaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public function getFilePathAttribute($value){
    $img = Image::make(public_path($value)); //your image I assume you have in public directory
    $img->insert(public_path('watermark.png'), 'bottom-right', 10, 10); //insert watermark in (also from public_directory)
    $img->save(public_path($value)); //save created image (will override old image)
    return $value; //return value
}
```

It is better to do it on upload so you do it Once not always when trying to access the image path from DB (less proccess) FYI: this will save already watermarked image

Comment: Thanks for pointing it is possible to override the old image, This will be very helpful.

Comment: @KiarieHenry It is better to on upload

Comment: I was also thinking the same but i was having two folders, the original photo folder and watermarked photo. Now I know the trick. Thanks @Froxz

Comment: @Froxz nice script but it creates one problem when i adding watermark to 3024*2016 pixel or up pixles  image the watremark not display properly. when zoom the image then it is showing please help !

Comment: i want you should answer my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451310/how-to-add-watermark-image-in-laravel-5-2-in-intervention-package