# How to add watermark image in laravel 5.2 in intervention package?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, watermark, intervention

I am using laravel 5.2 framework and i am using intervention package of laravel that runs fine for me. Now here i face one problem i don't know what i amd doing wrong. Please help:-

```
$myimage = Image::make(storage_path('app/images/test1.jpg'));
//Suppose $imyimage width is 3024 and height is 2016
$actualwidth = 3024;
$actualheight = 2016;
```

Now, when i tried these sizes 3024 * 2016 pixel then watermark is not visible while when i zoom the image then it is visible 
Now suppose i have width and height 1600*1027 pixel it shows me right in  center without zooming
I want want watermark in center in 3024*2016 pixel or any pixel with zooming the image.

```
$watermarkHeight =  Image::make(storage_path('watermark.png'))->height();
$watermarkWidth =  Image::make(storage_path('watermark.png'))->width();
$x = ($actualwidth - $watermarkWidth) / 2;
$y = ($actualheight - $watermarkHeight) / 2;
$img = Image::make(storage_path('app/images/test1.jpg'));
$img->insert(storage_path('watermark.png'), 'center',round($x),round($y));
$img->resize($actualwidth,$actualheight)->save(storage_path('app/images/watermark-test.jpg'));
```

Please Help me what i am doing wrong . Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your question is not clear for me, you try to put watermark on image with different width/height and you need this watermark to be centered and resized based on initial image? `,round($x),round($y)` you don't see it because of this values are to high.

Comment: yes exactly @Froxz i want watremark image on resized image that should be visible and in center also

Comment: then what is the solution @Froxz i want whatever the size is,, i want image to be centered and visible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood right your question, here is solution (not tested)

```
$watermark =  Image::make(storage_path('watermark.png'));
$img = Image::make(storage_path('app/images/test1.jpg'));
//#1
$watermarkSize = $img->width() - 20; //size of the image minus 20 margins
//#2
$watermarkSize = $img->width() / 2; //half of the image size
//#3
$resizePercentage = 70;//70% less then an actual image (play with this value)
$watermarkSize = round($img->width() * ((100 - $resizePercentage) / 100), 2); //watermark will be $resizePercentage less then the actual width of the image

// resize watermark width keep height auto
$watermark->resize($watermarkSize, null, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});
//insert resized watermark to image center aligned
$img->insert($watermark, 'center');
//save new image
$img->save(storage_path('app/images/watermark-test.jpg'));
```

Comment: very close now in every image watermark is very very zoom

Comment: @kunal check updated answer there is 3 ways of resize of the watermark, use  one that fits your needs.

Comment: how can i maintain the dpi of resized or uploaded image please help

Comment: i want you should answer this question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456351/how-to-maintain-the-dpi-dots-per-inch-of-an-image-in-laravel-5-2-using-interve