# How to add watermark when upload image using laravel using any library or custom development

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I am trying to add watermark to images using http://image.intervention.io library but not working here's my code given below 
I need to implement watermark dynamically when uploading or retrieving images

Controller Code

```
public function store(storeNewspaperJobFormValidation $request)
    {
        $values = $request->input();

        list($city, $catagory) = $this->_gettingValues($values);

        unset($values['city_id']);
        unset($values['catagory_id']);

        $values['slug'] = str_slug($values['organization_name'] . '-' . rand(1, 1000), '-');

        if ($request->hasFile('image_file')) {

            $request->file('image_file');
            $filename = $request->image_file->getClientOriginalName();

            $originalfile['image_file'] = $request->image_file->storeAs('public/newpaper_jobs', $filename);

            $data = array_merge($values, $originalfile);


            $newspaper = new newspaper_jobad($data);
            $newspaper->save();

            $insertedId = $newspaper->id;


            $this->_saveCatagoryNewspaperJobadbAssociations($catagory, $insertedId);

            $this->_saveNewspaperJobCities($city, $insertedId);

            //a flash message shold be shown that data successfully created
            flash('Data successfully added')->success();
            return back();

        } else

            flash('Data Not Inserted Image is Missing')->success();
        return back();

    }
```

Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;


class newspaper_jobad extends Model
{
    use Searchable;

    protected $fillable = ['organization_name', 'job_apply_link', 'job_description', 'city_id', 'province_id', 'sector_id', 'image_file', 'test_id', 'newspaper_id', 'catagory_id', 'slug', 'meta_keywords', 'meta_description', 'job_title'];


    public function getFilePathAttribute($value)
    {
        $img = Image::make("public/newpaper_jobs/$value"); //your image I assume you have in public directory
        $img->insert('public/favico.png', 'bottom-right', 10, 10); //insert watermark in (also from public_directory)
        $img->save("public/Storage/newpaper_jobs/$value"); //save created image (will override old image)
        return ($value); //return value
    }
```

Location of image is

```
public/Storage/newpaper_jobs/
```

Location of watermark image

```
public/favico.png
```

Comment: for image paths use `asset` helper like `Image::make(asset('newpaper_jobs/'. $value));`

Comment: refer this, it might be helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41182385/adding-watermark-on-image-from-databases-in-laravel-5-3

Answer (score 2):

After going through about 100 different "answers", here is the solution using intervention and Laravel storage:

```
// store uploaded image
$uploaded_image = request()->file('image')->store('public');

// add watermark and save
$image = Image::make(Storage::get($uploaded_image));
$image->insert(Storage::get('public/watermark.png'), 'bottom-right');
$image->save(Storage::path($uploaded_image));
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [spatie/laravel-medialibrary](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary) for managing my models media, it makes the process really easy. It's based on the concept of conversions, so you just set your model to have a media conversion with a watermark:

```
class ModelWithMedia extends Model implements HasMediaConversions
{

    /* Traits */

    use HasMediaTrait;

    /* Attributes */

    public function registerMediaConversions(Media $media = null)
    {
        // Watermark conversion
        $this->addMediaConversion($media->basename.'-watermark')
            ->watermark(public_path('/img/watermark.png'))
            ->nonQueued();
    }
}
```

It uses [spatie/image](https://github.com/spatie/image) for image modifications, so you can use any method available in the package and chain them together until you get your desired modification.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$image=$request->file($formFileName);

//watermark image
$watermark =\Image::make('img/sd_wat_60.png');

//Image which you want to upload
\Image::make($image->getRealPath())->insert($watermark, 'bottom-right')->save($path.$fileFinalName);
```